# Posts on Sidebar only

Tags: posts, pages, widgets, sidebar

I want to be able to add a post on my sidebar without it showing the text on the sidebar or it being linked to the menu. For example, if you click on the link below you'll see the *Katie Did What* blog. On the blog she has different content on her sidebar. If you click where it says "My Favorite Blogging Tools" it opens a whole different page that is not listed in me Menu.

http://www.katiedidwhat.com/

Please help!

Karla

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site you mentioned used a Text Widget.
Did you try to add a new image to the media library and then add a text widget on your sidebar?
Just copy the full path of the image you uploaded and then add a link surrounding the image.

Steps:

- Add an image in the Media Library.
- Copy the full path of the uploaded image.
- Go to **Appearance > Widgets**.
- Add a Text Widget to the sidebar.
- Type a title and then add an `img` HTML tag with the URL you copied previously.
- Add a anchor tag around the `img` tag.
- Save the changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering. When I add the text a new page does not appear. Whatever I type on the text widget will appear on the sidebar and I don't want that. I want the post to appear on a page without me having to put it on my main menu.

Comment: Hi again, let's see if I understand. In the website you shared the page doesn't appear in the main menu, is only accessible in the sidebar. If you create a new page and you don't want to appear in the menu you have to create a new menu under `Appearance > Menus` and select only the pages you want.
Then, in the sidebar, add the text widget and paste the page url you created.
I'm not sure if I'm missing something but since I don't know what theme you are using or your WordPress setup, is usually pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I will try this and will get back at you to let you know the results. I'm using the Teagan theme under Genesis.